# Auto-generate custom ID using mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want it to be in the format of "YYYY-###" where it gives the year and number ### incriminating starting from 1. ex: 2016-001, 2016-002, 2016-003,...

Comment: choose only one db tag, not 3.

Comment: Tell us more about where are you using this. And also why you want to do that. Usually this kind of auto-generated id arent recomend it. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Regardless of the DBMS this is a bad idea. You are violating 1NF by stuffing two values into a single tuple. You should have a column for your incrementing value and another for the year the row was created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Numbers/Tally table if you like.  I use a UDF to dynamically generate number ranges.   As you can see in the function call I set the range from 1 to 12 with an increment of 1

```
Declare @Table table (SomeField int)
Insert into @Table values 
(2015),(2016)


Select StringValue =cast(SomeField as varchar(25))+'-'+right('000'+cast(RetVal as varchar(25)),3)
      ,SomeField
      ,RetVal
 From  @Table A
 Join (Select RetVal=cast(RetVal as int) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](1,12,1)) B
   on (1=1)
```

Returns

```
StringValue SomeField   RetVal
2015-001    2015        1
2015-002    2015        2
2015-003    2015        3
2015-004    2015        4
2015-005    2015        5
2015-006    2015        6
2015-007    2015        7
2015-008    2015        8
2015-009    2015        9
2015-010    2015        10
2015-011    2015        11
2015-012    2015        12
2016-001    2016        1
2016-002    2016        2
2016-003    2016        3
2016-004    2016        4
2016-005    2016        5
2016-006    2016        6
2016-007    2016        7
2016-008    2016        8
2016-009    2016        9
2016-010    2016        10
2016-011    2016        11
2016-012    2016        12
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number] (@R1 money,@R2 money,@Incr money)

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](0,100,2)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal money)

As
Begin
    With NumbTable as (
        Select NumbFrom = @R1
        union all
        Select nf.NumbFrom + @Incr
        From NumbTable nf
        Where nf.NumbFrom < @R2
    )
    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal)

    Select NumbFrom from NumbTable Option (maxrecursion 0)

    Return
End
```